# Inaccessible disk after OS reinstall

Tags: permissions, raid, windows-server-2012

Our server has an OS RAID 1 and a separate 8 disk RAID 1 array.  It was originally running server 2008, but it crashed on us.  I attempted to fix the issue by removing the server from the domain, but when I tried to get back in, the local Administrator password didn't work, so I was unable to ever log back into windows.

Basically, I was forced to reinstall windows, so we installed server 2012.  The installation went fine.  The problem is that the 8-disk array is visible, but it is inaccessible due to permissions (or so it says).  However, when I try to forcibly overwrite the permissions on the disk, it says I cannot take control of the disk because I don't have read permissions on the drive.  So now we have almost 3 TB of data that is totally inaccessible.  How can I reset permissions on the disk?  I'm at a total loss here.

Comment: Eight disk...RAID 1? What?

Comment: Actually, I've done 4 and 6 disk RAID 1 with mdadm, it's really just a bigger mirror.  I've only done it when the disk's been partitioned so /boot is R1, / is R5, /cache is R0, where you've got partitions, and differing raid levels on those.

Comment: This seems like an odd question to migrate - old and possibly abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Taking ownership of the drive via drive properties/security/advanced might be a fair place to start before attempting to apply permissions. (I'm assuming that the physical disk & volume has been checked in disk manager and no issues shown there).